# CodeMirror preserve blank lines

Tags: codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am using CodeMirror to display JSON, XML and Plain Text output.

All is well with JSON and XML. But, my Plain Text output loses blank lines. I am setting the CodeMirror's *mode* property to null when displaying plain text. Is there any way to work-around this issue and force CodeMirror to preserve blank lines? I don't need any other formatting when displaying plain text.

Thank you.

Comment: CodeMirror preserves blank lines perfectly fine. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Marijn is right -- the issue is elsewhere.

Some other code was doing editor.autoFormatRange, which removed blank lines. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I have the same issue caused by the same reason, did you found a solution for the "autoFormatRange" not to remove empty lines?